# Error implementing a Custom Model Binder in Asp.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, custom-model-binder

im stuck with this very strange problem.
i have an API Controller named `AttendanceController` derived from `APIControllerFA` which is inturn derived from `ApiController`
here is the code

```
public class AttendanceController : ApiControllerFA
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage PostAttendance([ModelBinder(typeof(AttendanceRegistrationModelBinder))]AttendanceRegistrationModel model)
        {
            //checking model state for errors
            //throw new Exception("Just to throw an error ");

            ...........
```

As can be seen on the PostAttendance method i have a custom `ModelBinder` named `AttendenceRegistrationModelBinder` for which this is the code

```
public class AttendanceRegistrationModelBinder :  DefaultModelBinder
    {

        protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
        {
            if (propertyDescriptor.Name == "formJson")
            {
                string val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name).AttemptedValue;
                dynamic jsonVal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(val);
                propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, jsonVal);
                return;
                //SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext,propertyDescriptor,jsonVal);
            }
            base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
        }


    }
```

but when i try to access this controller using the Fiddler. i get an error saying

```
Could not create a 'IModelBinder' from 'AttendanceRegistrationModelBinder'. Please ensure it derives from 'IModelBinder' and has a public parameterless constructor
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are using the MVC model binder not the WebApi. It looks like you are deriving from `System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder` which implements `System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder`.

To create a custom model binder for WebApi you need to implement `System.Web.Http.IModelBinder`.

Take a look at the model binders available in WebApi e.g. the CompsiteModelBinder http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f079d76e57b5#src%2fSystem.Web.Http%2fModelBinding%2fBinders%2fCompositeModelBinder.cs.

Some useful resources [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/05/11/webapi-parameter-binding-under-the-hood.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx).

Have you considered using a [JToken](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures2ASPNETWebAPIInVisualStudio2012.aspx) for your Json form field this may work without a custom binder.