# WebAPI Custom ModelBinder inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, binders

I am trying to bind to the parent of a certain object type using WebAPI BindParameter. I am able to bind to the object itself (SomeObject), but not its parent (SomeOtherObject). This would cause me to have to have a specific BindParameter call for all possible inheritors of SomeObject. Is there a better way to bind the parameter type that would allow me to accomplish this?

The binders:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.BindParameter(typeof(SomeObject), new SetTrackerModelBinder()); 

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.BindParameter(typeof(SomeOtherObject), new SetTrackerModelBinder()); //Does not work.
```

The object structure:

```
public class SomeObject:SomeOtherObject{

}
public class AnotherObject:SomeOtherObject{

}
public class SomeOtherObject{

}
```

The action:

```
public void PostStuffs(SomeObject value) {}
```

Comment: How do you determine which concrete type must be deserialized into the base class (SomeObject or AnotherObject) ?. You could write a custom MediaTypeFormatter or ModelBinder, but you need to determine the type somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can try looking at my answer to the following post. I do not use ModelBinders though:

[WebApi Model Binding For Inherited Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515423/webapi-model-binding-for-inherited-types)