# send neatly formatted json data to asp.net web api instead of default [FromBody] behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to figure out a way to send a Json formatted data to a web api controller in a neat(more natural) way.

let me explain. Suppose I have this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public class StudentController : ApiController
{

    public void PostSomething([FromBody] string name, [FromBody] Student s) 
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

The json data that I WANT to post is something like this (as it is correctly formatted):

```
{
    "name" : "John",
    "student" : {
        "id" : "1",
        "age" : "22"
    }
}
```

But what I SHOULD send for the web api to `parameter bind` the objects should be like this:

```
{
    "John",
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "age" : "22"
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I use my desired json format, both `name` and `student` objects will be null in the `PostSomething` method of the controller.

How can I send a json request with a format similar to the first example to my web api controller?

Comment: The second example doesn't look like valid json to me, and fails on every validator I have tested it with.

Comment: That is exactly the case and you are totally right. But the web api controller only accepta the parameters if I send them this way. That is the problem

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear to me. Is that the JSON you need to receive from a 3rd party, or is that the JSON format you need to create in order to send to a 3rd party?

Comment: The first example is how i WANT to send the json request, the web api controller won't accept it. The second example is how web api accepts the json(and I dont like it to be this way)

Comment: Then you need to write your own descendant of the ParameterBindingAttribute and use that instead of [FromBody] to decorate your parameter. Problem is you will also have to parse this string yourself because it doesn't adhere to any standard - that's going to be a real pain. Can't you get the user to send a properly formatted request?

Comment: It is more of a matter of being neat. The user is actually an android application that is being made by our team too. Since we are using `Gson` for model binding in our client, we wanted to post json data like my first example. But thank you for you time. I solved the problem using rboe's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to consume the desired JSON structure you can change the method signature of the PostSomething and introduce a class that represents the sent data. E.g.

```
public class StudentTransferObject {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Student Student {get; set;}
}
```

With the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public class StudentController : ApiController
{    
    public void PostSomething([FromBody] StudentTransferObject studentInformation) 
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Still I cannot specify the name of the parameter as the key

Comment: actually I was wrong and your solution totally works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. [Read text](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/dec/13/accepting-raw-request-body-content-with-aspnet-web-api) from response body and parse the objects yourself:

   `[HttpPost]
   public async Task<string> PostSomething()
   {
       string result = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       //parse here how you want
       return result;
   }`
2. [Dynamic serialization](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/c-dynamic-object-and-json-serialization-with-json-net/) with [custom binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282014/webapi-custom-model-binding-of-complex-abstract-object) or [JToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795045/accessing-all-items-in-the-jtoken-json-net).